# Group contact cache deadlocks

Tags: smartgroups, cache

I have tried to activate the job specified in an entry in Eileen's blog but get the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the new release, I think it has a fix included for this issue: https://civicrm.org/blog/yashodha/announcing-civicrm-4619-and-479-release